# Scrollview goes under status bar when using KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native, scrollview

If you take a look on the left of the time on the status bar, you can see part of the scrollview showing. When scrolling up i can see the scrollview with all the elements ( pickers ,textinputs etc) scrolling underneath the statusbar.

[image]

My hierarchy looks like this

```
        <React.Fragment>
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={true} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.black, zIndex: 10000 }}>

           <View style={{flex:1}}>
           <Header/> //has certain height. had to add zIndex=10000 to avoid same issue
             <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
               <ScrollViewWithContent/>
             </KeyboardAvoidingView>
           </View>

          </SafeAreaView>
        </React.Fragment>
```

Are you seeing anything obviously off?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow:hidden;` will do the trick. However i feel like this shouldnt be happening in the first place. The original bug is a weird state where part of the scrollview shows ( the text ) and part of it doesnt ( the background )